# Spring Data JPA Hibernate Mariadb insert not working

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a rather large project that is not persisting rows. I am running with a local MariaDB instance on OSX 10.12. I have a simple Privilege entity. I start by dropping the Database with the command line. I start my application which first runs a data loader. Each entity in the data loader is checked for existence and then a new entity is saved if it doesn't already exist.

I save 3 Privileges and then findAll(). I get 3 entities back.

If I then go to the command line and query databases and tables, the database has been created as well as all the tables. All the tables have 0 rows. I've also checked the returned entity from the save and it matches the entity being saved.

SetupDataLoader.java:

```
@Component
public class SetupDataLoader implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>
{
....
        Privilege.READ_PRIVILEGE = createPrivilegeIfNotFound(Privilege.READ_PRIVILEGE_STRING);
        Privilege.WRITE_PRIVILEGE = createPrivilegeIfNotFound(Privilege.WRITE_PRIVILEGE_STRING);
        Privilege.PASSWORD_PRIVILEGE = createPrivilegeIfNotFound(Privilege.CHANGE_PASSWORD_PRIVILIGE_STRING);
        List<Privilege> privileges = this.privilegeService.getAll();
....

    @Transactional
    private final Privilege createPrivilegeIfNotFound(final String name)
    {
        Privilege privilege = this.privilegeService.findByName(name);
        if (privilege == null)
        {
            privilege = new Privilege(name);
            Privilege savedPrivilege = this.privilegeService.save(privilege);
            int i = 0;
        }
        return privilege;
    }
```

persistence.properties:

```
jdbc.driverClassName=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/field_server?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
jdbc.user=....
jdbc.pass=....
init-db=false
```

hibernate.properties:

```
hibernate.dialect=ws.daley.field.store.persistence.CustomMySQLDialect
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.format_sql=true
hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
hibernate.type=trace
```

CustomMySQLDialect.java:

```
public class CustomMySQLDialect extends MySQL57Dialect
{
    @Override
    public boolean dropConstraints() {return false;}
}
```

Privilege.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "privilege")
@Audited
public class Privilege extends FieldServerEntity<Privilege>
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static final String READ_PRIVILEGE_STRING = "READ_PRIVILEGE";
    public static final String WRITE_PRIVILEGE_STRING = "WRITE_PRIVILEGE";
    public static final String CHANGE_PASSWORD_PRIVILIGE_STRING = "CHANGE_PASSWORD_PRIVILEGE";

    public static Privilege READ_PRIVILEGE;
    public static Privilege WRITE_PRIVILEGE;
    public static Privilege PASSWORD_PRIVILEGE;

    public static List<Privilege> adminPrivileges;
    public static List<Privilege> userPrivileges;

    @Id
    @Getter @Setter private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "privileges")
    @Getter @Setter private Collection<Role> roles;

    public Privilege() {}

    public Privilege(final String name) {this.name = name;}

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {return Util.hashCode(this.LOGGER, this);}

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object obj) {return Util.equal(this, obj);}

    @Override
    public String toString() {return Util.toString(this.LOGGER, this);}

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Privilege privilege)
    {
        return this.name.compareTo(privilege.name);
    }
}
```

PrivilegeRepository.java:

```
public interface PrivilegeRepository extends INameRepository<Privilege>
{
}
```

INameRepository.java:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface INameRepository<T> extends JpaRepository<T, String>
{
    T findByName(String name);
}
```

PrivilegeService.java:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class PrivilegeService extends NameSubService<PrivilegeRepository, Privilege> implements IPrivilegeService
{
}
```

NameSubService/java:

```
public abstract class NameSubService<R extends INameRepository<T>, T extends FieldServerEntity<T>>
    extends SubService<R, T, String> implements INameService<T>
{
    @Override
    public T findByName(String name) {return this.repository.findByName(name);}
}
```

SubService.java:

```
public abstract class SubService<R extends JpaRepository<T, K>, T extends FieldServerEntity<T>, K extends Serializable> implements IService<T>
{
    @Autowired
    protected R repository;

    @Override
    public T save(T t) {return this.repository.saveAndFlush(t);}

    @Override
    public List<T> getAll() {return this.repository.findAll();}

    @Override
    public void delete(T t) {this.repository.delete(t);}
}
```

IService.java:

```
public interface IService<T extends FieldServerEntity<T>>
{
    T save(T node);
    List<T> getAll();
    void delete(T node);
}
```

FieldServerEntity.java:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@NoRepositoryBean
public abstract class FieldServerEntity<T> implements Comparable<T>, Serializable
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    public FieldServerEntity() {}

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "[...]";
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result;
        return result;
    }
}
```

INameService.java:

```
public interface INameService<T extends FieldServerEntity<T>> extends IService<T>
{
    T findByName(String name);
}
```

PersistenceJPAConfig.java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource({ "classpath:persistence.properties" })
@ComponentScan({ "ws.daley.field.store.persistence" })
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "ws.daley.field.store.persistence.dao")
public class PersistenceJPAConfig
{
    protected Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public PersistenceJPAConfig() {}

    public HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter()
    {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        return vendorAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory()
    {
        final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "ws.daley.field.store.persistence.model" });
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter());
//      em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource()
    {
        final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(this.env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(this.env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(this.env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
        dataSource.setPassword(this.env.getProperty("jdbc.pass"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager()
    {
        final JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation()
    {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }
}
```

Sorry for all the parameterization, but I have a LOT of classes that are similar and this was my solution. Also, this code was generally working earlier, I have made extensive changes to the UI with the tables populated from previous runs. I went back to do some database work and decided to reinitialize the database. Now I can't get rows properly inserted.

Here's the eclipse variable privileges from this.privilegeService.getAll():

```
[Privilege=[name="CHANGE_PASSWORD_PRIVILEGE"], Privilege=[name="READ_PRIVILEGE"], Privilege=[name="WRITE_PRIVILEGE"]]
```

I had meant to include the log:

```
webadmin - 2017-08-08 08:33:09,828 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener - Merging transient instance
webadmin - 2017-08-08 08:33:09,828 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener - Generated identifier: CHANGE_PASSWORD_PRIVILEGE, using strategy: org.hibernate.id.Assigned
webadmin - 2017-08-08 08:33:09,829 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener - Saving [ws.daley.field.store.persistence.model.Privilege#CHANGE_PASSWORD_PRIVILEGE]
webadmin - 2017-08-08 08:33:09,829 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue - Adding an EntityInsertAction for [ws.daley.field.store.persistence.model.Privilege] object
webadmin - 2017-08-08 08:33:09,829 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue - Adding insert with no non-nullable, transient entities: [EntityInsertAction[ws.daley.field.store.persistence.model.Privilege#CHANGE_PASSWORD_PRIVILEGE]]
webadmin - 2017-08-08 08:33:09,829 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue - Adding resolved non-early insert action.
webadmin - 2017-08-08 08:33:09,829 [main] TRACE org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager - Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@6efd83ac] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@1be3a294] bound to thread [main]
webadmin - 2017-08-08 08:33:09,830 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushing session
webadmin - 2017-08-08 08:33:09,830 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Processing flush-time cascades
webadmin - 2017-08-08 08:33:09,830 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade - Processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for: ws.daley.field.store.persistence.model.Priv
webadmin - 2017-08-08 08:33:09,830 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade - Done processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for: ws.daley.field.store.persistence.model.Priv
webadmin - 2017-08-08 08:33:09,830 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade - Processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for: ws.daley.field.store.persistence.model.Priv
webadmin - 2017-08-08 08:33:09,830 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade - Done processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for: ws.daley.field.store.persistence.model.Priv
webadmin - 2017-08-08 08:33:09,830 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade - Processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for: ws.daley.field.store.persistence.model.Priv
webadmin - 2017-08-08 08:33:09,830 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade - Done processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for: ws.daley.field.store.persistence.model.Priv
webadmin - 2017-08-08 08:33:09,831 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade - Processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for: ws.daley.field.store.persistence.model.Privilege
webadmin - 2017-08-08 08:33:09,831 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade - Done processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for: ws.daley.field.store.persistence.model.Privilege
webadmin - 2017-08-08 08:33:09,831 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade - Processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for: ws.daley.field.store.persistence.model.Privilege
webadmin - 2017-08-08 08:33:09,831 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade - Done processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for: ws.daley.field.store.persistence.model.Privilege
webadmin - 2017-08-08 08:33:09,831 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade - Processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for: ws.daley.field.store.persistence.model.Privilege
webadmin - 2017-08-08 08:33:09,831 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade - Done processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for: ws.daley.field.store.persistence.model.Privilege
webadmin - 2017-08-08 08:33:09,831 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Dirty checking collections
webadmin - 2017-08-08 08:33:09,831 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushing entities and processing referenced collections
webadmin - 2017-08-08 08:33:09,832 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Processing unreferenced collections
webadmin - 2017-08-08 08:33:09,832 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Scheduling collection removes/(re)creates/updates
webadmin - 2017-08-08 08:33:09,832 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushed: 1 insertions, 0 updates, 0 deletions to 6 objects
webadmin - 2017-08-08 08:33:09,832 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 0 collections
webadmin - 2017-08-08 08:33:09,832 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter - Listing entities:
webadmin - 2017-08-08 08:33:09,832 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter - ws.daley.field.store.persistence.model.Privilege{roles=null, name=READ_PRIVILEGE}
webadmin - 2017-08-08 08:33:09,833 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter - ws.daley.field.store.persistence.model.Privilege{roles=null, name=WRITE_PRIVILEGE}
webadmin - 2017-08-08 08:33:09,833 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter - ws.daley.field.store.persistence.model.Privilege{roles=null, name=CHANGE_PASSWORD_PRIVILEGE}
webadmin - 2017-08-08 08:33:09,833 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter - ws.daley.field.store.persistence.model.Priv{roles=null, name=WRITE_PRIVILEGE}
webadmin - 2017-08-08 08:33:09,833 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter - ws.daley.field.store.persistence.model.Priv{roles=null, name=CHANGE_PASSWORD_PRIVILEGE}
webadmin - 2017-08-08 08:33:09,833 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.util.EntityPrinter - ws.daley.field.store.persistence.model.Priv{roles=null, name=READ_PRIVILEGE}
webadmin - 2017-08-08 08:33:09,833 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Executing flush
webadmin - 2017-08-08 08:33:09,833 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister - Inserting entity: [ws.daley.field.store.persistence.model.Privilege#CHANGE_PASSWORD_PRIVILEGE]
webadmin - 2017-08-08 08:33:09,834 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger - 
    /* insert ws.daley.field.store.persistence.model.Privilege
        */ insert 
        into
            privilege
            (name) 
        values
            (?)
Hibernate: 
    /* insert ws.daley.field.store.persistence.model.Privilege
        */ insert 
        into
            privilege
            (name) 
        values
            (?)
webadmin - 2017-08-08 08:33:09,834 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl - Registering statement [sql : '/* insert ws.daley.field.store.persistence.model.Privilege */ insert into privilege (name) values (?)', parameters : [null]]
webadmin - 2017-08-08 08:33:09,834 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister - Dehydrating entity: [ws.daley.field.store.persistence.model.Privilege#CHANGE_PASSWORD_PRIVILEGE]
webadmin - 2017-08-08 08:33:09,834 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [CHANGE_PASSWORD_PRIVILEGE]
webadmin - 2017-08-08 08:33:09,835 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl - Releasing statement [sql : '/* insert ws.daley.field.store.persistence.model.Privilege */ insert into privilege (name) values (?)', parameters : ['CHANGE_PASSWORD_PRIVILEGE']]
webadmin - 2017-08-08 08:33:09,835 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl - Closing prepared statement [sql : '/* insert ws.daley.field.store.persistence.model.Privilege */ insert into privilege (name) values (?)', parameters : ['CHANGE_PASSWORD_PRIVILEGE']]
webadmin - 2017-08-08 08:33:09,835 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl - Starting afterQuery statement execution processing [ON_CLOSE]
webadmin - 2017-08-08 08:33:09,835 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl - Starting afterQuery statement execution processing [ON_CLOSE]
webadmin - 2017-08-08 08:33:09,835 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Post flush
webadmin - 2017-08-08 08:33:09,835 [main] TRACE org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport - Completing transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.saveAndFlush]
webadmin - 2017-08-08 08:33:09,836 [main] TRACE org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager - Removed value [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$DefaultCrudMethodMetadata@31b2c451] for key [public abstract java.lang.Object org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository.saveAndFlush(java.lang.Object)] from thread [main]
webadmin - 2017-08-08 08:33:09,836 [main] TRACE org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager - Bound value [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$DefaultCrudMethodMetadata@1a9cfd5f] for key [public abstract java.util.List org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository.findAll()] to thread [main]
webadmin - 2017-08-08 08:33:09,836 [main] TRACE org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager - Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@6efd83ac] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@1be3a294] bound to thread [main]
webadmin - 2017-08-08 08:33:09,836 [main] TRACE org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager - Retrieved value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@2d33aa31] for key [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@4887de2b] bound to thread [main]
```

I have since built a standard set of objects that doesn't use all the abstraction. It works the same way. The data seems to reside in memory but doesn't get persisted to MariaDB.

I don't seen any exceptions.

Comment: do you get any exception or stack-trace?

Comment: I see you have hibernate.show_sql=true. Can you add the printed prepared statements to the question? That will help us know what is going on